# Notificação Agendada Firebase API

Tags: android, firebase

Estou tentando agendar um horário específico e quero enviar uma notificação usando o Firebase. Eu estou trabalhando no projeto onde eu tenho que enviar a notificação logo apôs duas horas da data atual. Atualmente, minha notificação está funcionando em tempo real, mas não consigo encontrar uma maneira de programá-la para o horário específico.

Comment: ah varias maneiras, mas já que esta usando o firebase, da uma olhada aqui https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android#user-content-firebase-jobdispatcher-

Comment: No caso isto teria que ser feito no servidor?

Comment: Usando algum job, ou agendando com AlarmManager  por exemplo?

Comment: se for local pode ser pelo link que passei, job ou alarm, agora se for notificação push, tem o lado do servidor tb, formula melhor a pergunta e explica, posta o código. Fica mais fácil ajudar

Comment: Estou querendo agendar enviando pelo servidor php, é possivel?

Comment: cara da uma olhada aqui, https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server?hl=pt-br, do lado esquerdo tem tb o menu da parte android

Comment: Pode criar um serviço e usar com o AlarmManager,

Comment: Pelas minhas pesquisas acho que tenho que configurar com AlarmManager mesmo, não queria usar AlarmManager para economizar recursos do cel, mas não vai ter jeito, firebase não fornece suporte para isto via api, só pelo console.